# Eclipse crashes when opening a file with pydev

Tags: eclipse, crash, pydev

Every time I try to open a module with the python editor from pydev, whole eclipse crashes and i have no idea why.

The file is placed in the root, opening with (build-in) text editor works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No one is going to be able to answer your question until you give some context.

1. The extension of the file since eclipse may open the file diffently based on the extension. Try to open the file in a text editor instead of the default.
2. Operating system version
3. Eclipse version
4. File ownership and permissions set on the file you are trying to open and the directory it is in.
5. Does the directory path or file name have funny characters. spaces punctuation other than `.`